# Is it possible to split selection into multi cursor in Intellij IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea, multicursorediting

In sublime you can select a part of text or even whole text by Ctrl+A and tap Ctrl+Shift+L will split your selection into multi cursor, it is especially useful when you deal with a big selection, and it's a bit horribly to select it by Mouse3 dragging...

[image]

Is it possible in Idea?

Answer (score 1):

On my machine the keyboard shortcut to make this happen is `alt + shift + insert`. The command is called *column selection mode*.

[image]

Comment: That functionality is available for you via mouse3 dragging. It seems like you havent tried to use that hotkey in sumblime text, these things arent the same. Also it can help only when you're dealing with mouse... But sometimes you want to click Ctrl+W a few times to select a whole block of text and split selection to multicursor